# Linux shell: How to remove lines from one files based on the indexes in another

Tags: bash, scripting, sh

I have two files, one contains only the data and it is a "CSV fixed width" like this (I am putting here a simplified version of the data, there are many more columns and lines in the original data):

```
1    "john smith"    other fields
2    "john doe"      other fields
3    "john black"    other fields
4    "john brown"    other fields
5    "john white"    other fields
```

The first column contains the indexes and the fields are padded in 5 chars.

The second file is just:

```
2
4
```

What I am trying to get is a 3rd file that contains only the lines that has not index in the second file. So:

```
1    "john smith"    other fields
3    "john black"    other fields
5    "john white"    other fields
```

I tried different commands, `awk`, `grep`, `join`, `tr` etc but I could not get it.

Example:

```
join -1 1 -2 1 file1.txt file2.txt
awk 'NR==FNR{a[NR]=$0; next} {print a[FNR], $0}' file1.txt file2.txt
```

Any help?

Comment: Please post here your attempts!!

Comment: CSV and fixed-width are mutually exclusive; either the columns are delimited by a fixed character, or the boundary between each column is implied by the width of the column.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For file2 , store its first column in array a. Then if  $1 is not present in array a for file2 ,then only print.

```
awk 'NR==FNR{a[$1]=$1;next} !($1 in a){print $0}' file2 file1
1    "john smith"    other fields
3    "john black"    other fields
5    "john white"    other fields
```

Comment: `awk` is awesome.

Comment: there was an issue with one file: an extra character `\r` before `n` in the indexes file. I removed it and it works now thank you.

Answer (score 2):

When the files are sorted as in the question, you can use the `join` command:

```
join -v 1 file1 file2
```

Explanation:

By default the `join` command joins the rows based on the value of the first column of each file. `-v1` reverts those operation making is just print lines of file1 which does not join with a row of file2

One thing, the above command expects both file1 and file2 being sorted, meaning it will not work if the input files are not sorted. You can use process substitution to ensure that they are sorted:

```
join -v 1 <(sort file1) <(sort file2)
```

If the original order of lines is important and need to be preserved `join` can't be used. I suggest to use `awk` in that case.

Comment: that didn't work for me because with the original files it returns some missing sort error

Comment: @Randomize You can use process substitution to sort the files before passing them to the `join` command. I've added that

Comment: That assumes you can sort the file; the original order may be important.

Comment: @chepner As you said, it *may* be important. Nothing says that it *is* important. No reason to down-vote the `join` command in a situation that is one of it's primary use-cases. Especially since the files in the question *are* sorted

Comment: If they were sorted, you wouldn't need to resort them.

Comment: I've elaborated on that fact in the explanation.

Answer (score 0):

`perl` solution, similar to `awk 'NR==FNR{a[$1];next} !($1 in a)' file2 file1`

```
$ perl -lane 'if(!$#ARGV){ $h{$F[0]}=1 }else{ print if !$h{$F[0]} }' file2 file1
1    "john smith"    other fields
3    "john black"    other fields
5    "john white"    other fields
```

- `-a` split input line on spaces and save to `@F` array
- `if(!$#ARGV){ $h{$F[0]}=1 }` initialize hash variable with first field of `file2` line as key value
- `else{ print if !$h{$F[0]} }` for `file1` lines, print based on first field as key in already saved hash variable

Also, a simpler version by taking advantage of the fact that `file2` has different number of fields compared to `file1`

```
$ perl -lane '$h{$F[0]}=1 if !$#F; print if !$h{$F[0]}' file2 file1
1    "john smith"    other fields
3    "john black"    other fields
5    "john white"    other fields
```

The same can be applied with `awk` of course:

```
$ awk 'NF==1{a[$1]} !($1 in a)' file2 file1
1    "john smith"    other fields
3    "john black"    other fields
5    "john white"    other fields
```

Answer (score 0):

```
grep -vEf "$(sed 's/\(.*\)/^\1[:blank:]/' file2)" file1
```